# SpriteKit (Swift) orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am making/made a game in landscape orientation and have a Facebook and a twitter button in the main menu to either open the app or Safari. 
The problem I have is that the app or safari opens up in portrait mode and when I switch back to my game it briefly shows everything in portrait before changing back to landscape. It also shows you a multitasking preview in portrait.

It is not a big deal but obviously for that brief 1-2 seconds the game is in portrait mode everything is squashed and it looks sort of ugly and unprofessional. This only happens when you use those 2 social media buttons, when you just switch to a portrait app yourself via multitasking the game will stay in landscape upon return.

I have being trying to figure it out but I cannot find anything, especially for swift. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

PS. This is the code I used for the social media parts, I think its pretty straight forward and boiler plate.

```
//MARK: - Load Social Media
func loadFacebook() {

    var appURL = NSURL(string: "APP ID HERE")
    var webURL = NSURL(string: "WEB ID HERE")

    if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appURL!)) {
        // App
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appURL!)
    } else {
        // Safari
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(webURL!)
    }
}

func loadTwitter() {

    var appURL = NSURL(string: "APP ID HERE")
    var webURL = NSURL(string: "WEB ID HERE")

    if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appURL!)) {
        // App
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appURL!)
    } else {
        // Safari
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(webURL!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here for answer as this is still an issue where there is not a lot of information about.

[Swift sprite kit landscape only forced into portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230280/swift-sprite-kit-landscape-only-forced-into-portrait)